# Execute command inside kubernetes pod (bash script)

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to execute a command inside postgres container from shell script. This is what I have so far:

`kubectl exec -it <postgres_pod> -n <deployment> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d database -c 'select count from table where name='FOO';'"`

I am getting the following error:

`ERROR:  column "foo" does not exist
LINE 1: select count from table where name=FOO;
                                           ^`

The query runs fine inside the container so there must be something wrong with the way I am passing the command. I did try another query:

```
kubectl exec -it <postgres_pod> -n <deployment> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d database -c 'select * from table;'"
```

This runs fine. So, I am guessing that its someting with the way I am passing the where clause `where name='FOO'`. How can I get this to work. Kindly help me out.

**Update:**

Tried escaping using:

**1: Double Quotes**

`kubectl exec -it <postgres_pod> -n <deployment> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d database -c 'select count from table where name=\"FOO\";'"`

```
ERROR:  column "FOO" does not exist
LINE 1: select count from table where name="FOO";
                                            ^
```

**2: Single Quotes**

`kubectl exec -it <postgres_pod> -n <deployment> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d database -c 'select count from table where name=\'FOO\';'"`

```
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used `$$` **[dollar-quoted string](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)** in where clause and escaped them using `/$`.

```
kubectl exec -it <postgres_pod> -n <deployment> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d database -c 'select count from table where name=\$\$FOO\$\$;'"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the quotes are not properly escaped and then FOO is assumed to be a column name.

Try

```
kubectl exec -it <pod_id> -n <deployment> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d database -c 'select count from table where name=\"FOO\";'"
```

Comment: I cant escape using `\"FOO\"`. I guess its because postgres doesn't allows where clause with `" "` double quotes. How can I escape single qutoes `' '`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Query condition element, name='value' is expected to be within single quotes.

Try this: it works!

```
kubectl exec -it <pod_id> -n <deployment> -- bash -c "psql -U postgres -d database -c \"select count from table where name='FOO'\""
```